# Is it possible to log all file reads performed by an application in Windows 7?

Tags: privacy, logging, file-access

I have a piece of software I'm supposed to be running on my computer. The only thing I'm slightly worried about is the files it reads, as it's closed-source and slightly fishy.

I know it's not malware, but I'd like to see if it accesses, for example, my personal documents. Optimally, I'd like to be able to kill it in that case.

Is this setup possible? I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium on my laptop. I do have multiple computers if needed, and I'm prepared to write code to use the Windows API or other things if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process monitor can do that for you:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx